# How to change a QLabels alignment from property editor in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I am trying to change the alignment of a QLabel (to AlignRight). Should it be possible to do that from Qt Designers Property Editor? In my project, I cannot edit that field! Why?

[image]

Comment: The property editor is a treeview, and `accessibleDescription`, `accessibleName`, `alignment` and `baseSize` should all be expandable. If you double-click the property name, it should expand it, which will allow editing. The question is why there are no clickable arrows to the left of the property names, as is normal for a treeview. In my stand-alone Qt Designer application, the arrows are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on "alignment" it will drop down then you can select

[image]